# How to set prefilled input field active with Jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a calculator widget where I can enter random values into an inputfield and then the widget automatically calculates when clicking the "go"-button.

Now I want to insert/prefill the value into this input field, since the value which needs to be calculated comes from a server. The issue though is, that this input field apparently only reacts on keypress. I tried to do this:

```
$('input[name="value"][data-type-money]').val('150.000').focus();
```

and

```
$('input[name="value"][data-type-money]').val('150.000').select();
```

which prefills the input field with the desired value but when I click the "go" button the calculation fails as long I dont enter the value manually into the input field. So, in the end my solution does not work.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: What are you using to send the data to the server? Ajax? Can we see that code?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Sorry, the calculator is an external script e.g. widget. I do not have access to the code directly... :-s

Comment: Do you have any error in the developer console? I tried your script and it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/y63rkvL9/. Maybe it's a format problem (comma ',' instead of dot '.' for decimal numbers)?

Answer (score 0):

Edit, Updated

> the input field is  -
>   and reacts only on keypress, I mean when value is entered manually

If `input` `value` property cannot be changed , try replacing the element in `DOM` with value set at `html` using `.replaceWith()`

```js
$('input[name="value"][data-type-money]')
.replaceWith("<input name=value data-type-money type=text value=150.00 />")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input name="value" data-type-money type="text" />
```

Comment: Hi, the input field is `<input name="value" data-type-money type="text">` - and reacts only on keypress, I mean when value is entered manually... so your solution does not work :-/

Comment: @Steve Hi, is jQuery available in document ? Try using `.replaceWith()` ; see updated post

Answer (score 0):

If data changes frequently you can also use the setInterval function:

```
<input name="value" data-type-money="money">
setInterval (function(){
    var moneyValue = "150.000";
    $('input[name="value"][data-type-money]').val(moneyValue);
},1000);
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/85pbnnu1/

or you can just do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="value"][data-type-money]').val('150.000').change();
});
```